# fetch all using prepared statements php

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problems with a php script. I coded a php script about a year ago before i learned prepared statements http://pastebin.com/WxXGnqLh and now i am trying to convert this to use prepared statements. In the pastebin link you can see i use mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) so i am trying to do the same when i use prepared statments. But it can't get it to work. I have been looking here on stackoverflow and i have been googling for hours now. I hope someone can help me.

So this is the code i got so far and it does not print out anything. Its just a blank page

```
<?php
include('config/dbconf.php');
$guid = 1;
$slotmin = 0;
$slotmax = 18;

mysqli_select_db($conn, "characters");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT item FROM character_inventory WHERE guid = ? AND slot BETWEEN ? AND ?");
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $guid, $slotmin, $slotmax);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['item'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Blank page is probably an error. Have you looked at error logs? If you output anywhere else on page do you get something? The `fetch` should be the same assuming you get back a result object.

Comment: Well. I can echo anywhere in the script except in the while loop. If i use for example echo "test"; in while loop it does not show up on page. But if i use echo anywhere outside the while loop it shows up on the page

Comment: Echoing between `if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {` and `while ` works?

Comment: Actually i tried it just before i read this comment and it was blank there too. But i tried echo above if($stmt->num_rows > 0) and that worked just fine

Comment: So it means the query doesnt find any rows for some reason. but if i run query in database it works just fine

Comment: If you var_dump `$result` and `$stmt` what are you seeing?

Comment: Nevermind. I solved it myself now after hours of testing. Here is how i solved it http://pastebin.com/swZnZSE4 added the rest of the code aswell and it all works perfectly fine now :)